# How to assign a literal to a variable and then use the same variable later in the module?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a code to emulate a Bulletin Board System (BBS) in python.

With this code I want to give the user the option to either view a message already entered or enter a message to be viewed later.

My code is as follows:

```
def BBS():
 print("Welcome to UCT BBS")
 print("MENU")
 print("(E)nter a message")
 print("(V)iew message")
 print("(L)ist files")
 print("(D)isplay file")
 print("e(X)it")

selection=input("Enter your selection:\n")

 if selection=="E" or selection=="e":
    message=input("Enter the message:\n")
 elif selection=="V" or selection=="v":
    if message==0:
        print("no message yet")
    else:
        print(message)
 elif selection=="L" or selection=="l":
    print("List of files: 42.txt, 1015.txt")
 elif selection=="D" or selection=="d":
    filename=input("Enter the filename:\n")
    if filename=="42.txt":
        print("The meaning of life is blah blah blah ...")
    elif filename=="1015.txt":
        print("Computer Science class notes ... simplified")
        print("Do all work")
        print("Pass course")
        print("Be happy")
    else:
        print("File not found")
 else:
    print("Goodbye!")

BBS()
```

When entering a message the code is supposed to display the message after v is selected or if no message is entered, "no message yet" is supposed to be displayed if v is selected.

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 15, in BBS
builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'message' referenced before assignment
```

when selecting v while using WingIDE.

Please help me correct this code.

Comment: I'd also use `str.lower` instead of always testing upper and lower case scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `message` is a local variable in your function. When the function ends, the value it was given is lost, even if you run the function again. To address this, you need to change something in your code, though what to change may depend on how you want to organize your program.

One option is to make it a global variable, which can be repeatedly accessed if the function is run more than once. To do this, first assign it a value at global level (outside the function), then use a `global` statement inside the function to make it clear to Python that it's the global name you want to access.

```
message = None

def BBS():
    global message
    # other stuff

    if foo():
        message = input("Enter a message: ")
    else:
        if message:
            print("The current message is:", message)
        else:
            print("There is no message.")
```

Another option would be to stick with a local variable, but keep the logic of your program all within the same function. That is, if you want a user to be able to make several entries, you need to have a loop inside the function to contain them. Here's how that might look:

```
def BBS():
   message = None # local variable

   while True: # loop until break
       if foo():
           message = input("Enter a message: ")
        elif bar():
            if message:
                print("The current message is:", message)
            else:
                print("There is no message.")
        else:
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
```

A final, and more complicated (but also more permanent and scalable) option would be to use something outside of your program to store the message. This lets it persist between runs of the program, and perhaps be seen by different users at different times. For a serious system I'd suggest a database, but for a "toy" system you can probably get away with simple text files. Here's an example of that:

```
def BBS():
    if foo():
        with open("message.txt", "w") as f:
            message = input("Enter a message: ")
            f.write(message)
    else:
        try:
            with open("message.txt", "r") as f:
                message = f.read()
                print("The current message is:", message)
        except (FileNotFoundError, OSError):
            print("There is no message.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `message` is *only* ever assigned in *one* `if` branch. If the *other* branch is selected instead, the variable is never defined.

Give it an empty value first:

```
 message = None

 if selection=="E" or selection=="e":
      message=input("Enter the message:\n")
 elif selection=="V" or selection=="v":
      if not message:
          print("no message yet")
      else:
          print(message)
```